# why header cells are not aligned with the body cells?

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

> rowData: any = [];rowModelType = 'serverSide';
> defaultColDef: any = { width: 50,  sortable: true, resizable: true,  };
> columnDefs: any = [];rowSelection = 'single'; public getRowHeight: any;
> private paramRefreshAgGrid: any; private gridColumnApi: any;
> private gridApi: any;
> constructor() {
> this.gridOption()
> } gridOption() {
> this.columnDefs = [
> { headerName: 'نوع ارز',field: 'currencyCode',width: 200,
> },{ headerName: 'خرید',field: 'buyEts',   width: 200, },
> { headerName: 'انتخاب', field: 'sellEts2',    width: 200, },
> { headerName: 'خرید',  field: 'buyEts3', width: 200, },
> {  headerName: 'انتخاب', field: 'sellEts',width: 200, },
> { headerName: 'خرید اضافه', field: 'buyExternalCheque',  width: 200 }
> ,{  headerName: 'مبلغ', field: 'buyMoney', width: 200,}, ]; }
> onGridReady(params: any) {
> const $this = this;
> if (params) {
> this.gridApi = params.api;this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
> this.paramRefreshAgGrid = params; }
> const datasource = {
> getRows(params: any) {
> const data: any = [
> {currencyCode: 'Ford2', buyEts: 'Mondeo', sellEts: 32000,  sellEts2: 32000 , sellEts3: 32000 , buyExternalCheque: 500 ,
> buyMoney: 100000},
> ]
> params.successCallback(data, data.total);
> $this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
> }
> };
> if (params) {
> params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
> }
> }
>
> ```html
> <ag-grid-angular
>   style="width: 100%;"
>   [ngStyle]="{'height': '50vh'  }"
>   id="logGrid"
>   class="ag-theme-balham"
>   [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>   [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
>   [enableRtl]="true"
>   [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
>   [animateRows]="false"
>   [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
>   [debug]="true"
>   [rowData]="rowData"
>   [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight"
>   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>   [paginationPageSize]="100"
>   [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true"
> </ag-grid-angular>
> ```

I use the  "ag-grid-angular": "20.2.0", in Angular 11 when I scroll the header The header cells are not aligned with the body cells.[image]

What solution do you have to fix this error?
thanks !!

Comment: Please provide the code so that it can be answered precisely. Thank you

Comment: update question

Comment: I have this error only in Chrome Version 5  89.0.4389.114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version `20.2.0` of ag-grid-angular is 2 years old. Try installing the latest version of `ag-grid-community` and `ag-grid-angular` - I would also delete node_modules folder afterwards and do a clean `npm install`

This may solve the problem (or at least narrow it down)

**Note** You should highlight in the question that the issue is only occurring in Chrome

Comment: You are right , But when I use version 25, lazy loading does not work ,value of property endRow and startRow was undefined in param.request